# no configurations in cmake project with visual studio

Tags: c++, cmake

When I add a new header or cpp file in the current cmake project, it shows up as no configurations in visual studio and the include (path I added in cmakelist) does not work properly.
If I create a new cmake cache after including it in main, then it is displayed in the project. However, when I delete the include sentence, the phrase no configurations appears again. How do I solve this?

Comment: I just looked into the current project of mine. Headers do have a configuration if they are included somewhere. Otherwise, they show `There are no property pages for the selection.` It seems it's the same in my case like described by you. However, I never noticed it before. It doesn't seem to have any impact to anything... (A header cannot be compiled on its own. Thus, there are no essential properties which had to be there.)

Comment: I put the cpp files corresponding to the header file in add_library and it solved it.